# Random Forest Regression for Multiple Groups

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, random-forest

I have monthly weather data all sampled from the past four years for about 50 different locations. Is there a way I can create a singular Random Forest Regression model that creates predictions for all 50 locations on their own? I don't want to have to create 50 different models, as that seems time-expensive. I don't think one-hot-encoding the names of the locations works, because the train/test/split then only takes the data from one of the locations to test with.

My data looks something like this:

Month Year Location Temp

3     2018 city1    42

3     2018 city2    50

3     2018 city3    30

4     2018 city1    50

4     2018 city2    55

4     2018 city3    60

...

12    2021 city1    20

12    2021 city2    40

12    2021 city3    30

And I want predictions for the next *x* number of months for city1, city2, city3, and so on.

Comment: Can you clarify which input are output are you looking for?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think Random Forest Regression is not the most appropriate model for this kind of task. A more appropriate model is a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN). Your problem fits exactly as a many-to-many sequence prediction as described in [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/models-sequence-prediction-recurrent-neural-networks/) blog.

In your skin, I would create a list of 50 RNN models and train for each city separately (can be done programmatically and reasonably quick with multiple processes and threads depending on the power of your computer and the size of your data).

To get a startup code, you can google *many-to-many model prediction with RNN*.An example is [this](https://goodboychan.github.io/python/deep_learning/tensorflow-keras/2020/12/09/01-RNN-Many-to-many.html) blog post.